# Plot weekly data from DataFrame of daily data

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a Julia DataFrame like so:

```
│ Row  │ date               │ users │ posts │ topics │ likes │ pageviews │
│      │ Date               │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64  │ Int64 │ Int64     │
├──────┼────────────────────┼───────┼───────┼────────┼───────┼───────────┤
│ 1    │ Date("2020-06-16") │  1    │  3    │ 4      │ 7     │ 10000     │
│ 2    │ Date("2020-06-15") │  2    │  2    │ 5      │ 8     │ 20000     │
│ 3    │ Date("2020-06-14") │  3    │  3    │ 6      │ 9     │ 30000     │
```

I would like a plot of posts vs date, but the daily data is too noisy, so I'd
like to take sum the posts for every week and plot that instead? What's the easiest
way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

The TimeSeries package provides various utilities to work with TimeSeries data.
In this case, you can use the `collapse` to convert from daily to weekly data:

```
julia> using TimeSeries, DataFrames

julia> ta = TimeArray(df.date, df.posts)
1311×1 TimeArray{Int64,1,Date,Array{Int64,1}} 2016-10-19 to 2020-06-16
│            │ A     │
├────────────┼───────┤
│ 2016-10-19 │ 1     │
│ 2016-10-20 │ 2     │
│ 2016-10-21 │ 3     │
│ 2016-10-23 │ 4     │
...

julia> weekly = collapse(ta, week, last, sum)
192×1 TimeArray{Int64,1,Date,Array{Int64,1}} 2016-10-23 to 2020-06-16
│            │ A     │
├────────────┼───────┤
│ 2016-10-23 │ 10    │
│ 2016-10-28 │ 22    │
│ 2016-11-06 │ 34    │
...

julia> using Gadfly
julia> plot(DataFrame(weekly)[1:end-1,:], x=:timestamp, y=:A, Geom.line(), Guide.ylabel("Weekly sum of Posts"), Guide.xlabel("Week"))
```

Comment: how do you control here which day is the start of the week?

Answer (score 2):

in DataFrames you can use `groupby` with `combine` as follows:

```
julia> using Statistics, Dates, Pipe;
julia> df = DataFrame(date = range(Date(2000, 01, 01), Date(2020, 01, 01), step = Day(1)));
julia> df.val = rand(nrow(df));
julia> @pipe df |>
           transform(_,
               :date => ByRow(year) => :year,
               :date => ByRow(week) => :week # 1:52
           ) |>
           groupby(_, [:week, :year]) |>
           transform(_, :val => mean)
```

If you want a moving average, you can use the following function

```
julia> function lagged_mean(x, b)
           map(1:length(x)) do i
               i < b ? missing : mean(@view x[i-b+1:i])
           end
       end

julia> lagged_mean(df.val, 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposal that allows to control which day you use for the start of the week (I use here Monday) and is also robust to missing data (dates can be repeated in the dataset):

```
df.weekno = Dates.days.(df.date .- Date(2000, 1, 3)) .÷ 7
combine(groupby(df, :weekno), :val => sum)
```

Note that the performance vs using `Week` is 3.5x faster:

```
julia> @btime transform($df,:date => (d->floor.(d,Week)) => :week);
  63.699 μs (68 allocations: 175.47 KiB)
julia> @btime transform($df,:date => (d->Dates.days.(d .- Date(2000, 1, 3)) .÷ 7) => :week);
  18.900 μs (74 allocations: 175.64 KiB)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to utilize floor? `using Dates; dfw = transform(df,:date => (d->floor.(d,Week)) => :week); combine(groupby(dfw,:week), :pageviews => sum)`

Comment: How do you start your week here by Sunday (Japan) or Saturday (Middle East)? This is also 3.5x slower than my code (see my edit)

Comment: With Julia 1.4.2 on a  i7-10710U CPU there is no performance difference at all.

Comment: I tested on Julia 1.5.0 beta1 running  i7-10510U, Windows with the dataframe in genauguy's example. How big was your dataframe?

Comment: It was tiny (3 rows) but under Linux.